# Dynamic EmbeddedDocument with mongoDB - MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

So, according to the MongoEngine documentation:

https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html

a document of type A needs to inherit from DynamicDocument in order for us to be able to save an object (of type A) that has additional fields than the ones  "officially" declared.

How can I make an EmbeddedDocument behave like a DynamicDocument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [Dynamic Schemas](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#dynamic-document-schemas).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that type in the API. Thanks!

Comment: It's nice to have an easy question from time to time :)